# EXCEL IF statement?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making an order list in excel, with f.e. paying date, order date, shipping date, price, delivery date etc. I want to make a column "completed" that automatically gets the value "1" or "yes" when the item arrived and the payment etc. is done, so when everything is filled in. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With data in columns **A** through **M**, in **N1** enter:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A1:M1)=COLUMNS(A1:M1),1,0)
```

The advantage of this type of formula is that it will auto-adjust if you add/remove columns.

Comment: i guess it is "count" iso "counta", but when i enter either of this it says there is a formula fault.

Comment: @EwoutSchokker  My formulas use the **English** function names..........what language is your version of Excel using?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use something like this, which will automatically enter a "yes" in the target offset column if a value in column B meets your criteria. Adjust according to your requirements.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B2:B305")) Is Nothing Then

           If Target = vbNullString Then

                Target = "payment made"   'or whatever you want to use
                Target.Offset(0, 12) = "Yes"   'which would be column N
            Else

                Target = vbNullString    'if the value in column B is removed
                Target.Offset(0, 12) = vbNullString   'column N is reutrned to blank

            End If

    End If
End Sub
```